# Correct way to handle swipes between UIViews

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have two views that I want to show using paging control on home screen of my app.
If user swipes on UI, it should show second view which is UITableView. First view is also UITableview.

I want to know the correct way of handling this swipes and add two round images that indicate selected page.
Whether I should go for scroll view paging or use gesture recogniser.

What is better way of doing this?

Comment: Also I want to add two round images that indicate selected page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the two UITableViews into a UIScrollView with pagination.

UIScrollView already handles the swipe for you and also it has the bounce animation from the pagination.

If you were to manually handle swipe gesture, you'll likely have to implement your own **bounce animation** and also **swipe interruption** in case the user swipes back the other way while the view is being transitioned across.

Comment: Also I want to add two round images that indicate selected page. Will UIPageViewController allow me to do so? And how?

Comment: Two rounded images? the UIPageControl element already gives you the paging dots you see on the Apple home screens. You'll want to Google how to track the current page in a UIScrollView if you want to display the correct dot.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you should use a UIPageViewController.

[Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)

**Edit**

If you want to add some sort of UIPageControl to your UIPageViewController, you need to use these 2 methods (from UIPageViewControllerDataSource):

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
```

Here's a complete tutorial on using UIPageViewController (with a page control, like you want).
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/using-scrollstyle-with-uipageviewcontroller/

Comment: Also I want to add two round images that indicate selected page. Will UIPageViewController allow me to do so? And how?